# Best way to handle image pre-loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, backbone.js, amazon-web-services

So I'm building an application, much like pinterest, that makes heavy use of infinite feeds. Each card has an image associated with it and I'm now exploring options to make the infinite scrolling as fast as possible.

For tech, I use [backbone.marionette](http://marionettejs.com/), [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), and [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/).

My implementation flow goes something like this:

1. Catch feed `onscroll` event
2. If page is above X percent scrolled, fire custom `infinitescroll` event
3. Make ajax request for specific card set
4. Create a card `Marionette.ItemView` and associated model based on each object in returned data array
5. Append each view to the feed's `Marionette.CollectionView` in a `hidden` state
6. Wait until each view from set has been appended to the `Marionette.CollectionView`
7. Register `imagesLoaded` listener to `Marionette.CollectionView`
8. On `imagesLoaded` event, reload isotope grid and `fadeIn` the `hidden` `ItemViews`

The bottle neck here is waiting for the `imagesLoaded` event to fire after all images for cards have been downloaded from an Amazon S3 server. One major optimization I can think of is image preloading.

I can figure out the next set's AWS URL, so I understand that I can 'pre-download' the images and create a `<img>` element for each upcoming card, but I'm a little fuzzy on what this actually does, how it ties into image caching, and whether or not this is the best method to implement.

Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish in the end.
If you'd like to show your feed as soon as possible, and do something after the image has loaded, then the easiest way would be not to use imagesLoaded, and just listen to the 'load' event in the ItemView, e.g. events: { "load img": "onImageLoaded" }. Or, more probable, as you need to catch it in the collection view:

```
 triggers: {"load img" : "image:loaded" }
```

If, however, you want to show the card only after you have the image, then the easiest way would be to prefetch the image:

```
img = new Image()
img.onload = function() { /*create the view*/ };
img.src = "s3 url";
```